# Trouble loading data using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Detail function based component that gets data from an API for a home rental listing. It has loading setup to wait for the data to be retrieved before displaying any of if (like anyone does). Has been working perfectly but I now added a location to the listings, and even though the data is their, it gives me an undefined error. Everything else gets displayed fine when I comment out the location part??? see the code below:

For example:

when I do {listing.name} OR {listing.numberOfGuests} those are fine. But when I do {listing.location.city} I get undefined, even though it is there I console.log() it everytime.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axiosInstance from '../../api';
import ReviewForm from '../Listings/ReviewForm';
import Reviews from '../Listings/Reviews';
import ReserveForm from '../Listings/ReserveForm';

//material ui
import { Container, Typography, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

//antd
import { Row, Col, Carousel, Divider } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  titleView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '100px',
    width: '960px',
    marginTop: '30px',
    padding: '5px',
    paddingLeft: '20px',
  },
  listingView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '450px',
    width: '670px',
    marginTop: '30px',
    marginBottom: '20px',
    marginRight: '30px',
  },
  listingDetails: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '350px',
    marginTop: '12px',
  },
  bookingView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '450px',
    width: '260px',
    marginTop: '30px',
    marginBottom: '20px',
    paddingTop: '20px',
  },
  reviewView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '550px',
    marginTop: '30px',
  },
  listingImg: {
    width: '650px',
    height: '430px',
    marginTop: '10px',
  },
});

const Detail = () => {
  const [listing, setListing] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { listingId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axiosInstance.get(`/listings/${listingId}`);
      setListing(result.data.listing);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  //console.log(listing.location);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <>
          <Row justify='center'>
            <Col>
              <Container className={classes.listingView}></Container>
            </Col>

            <Col>
              <Container className={classes.bookingView}></Container>
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row justify='center'>
            <Container
              className={classes.listingDetails}
              maxWidth='md'
            ></Container>
          </Row>

          <Row justify='center'>
            <Container maxWidth='md' className={classes.reviewView}></Container>
          </Row>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Row justify='center'>
            <Container className={classes.titleView} maxWidth='md'>
              <Typography variant='h4'>{listing.title}</Typography>
              <Typography color='textSecondary'>
                {listing.numberOfGuests} guests | {listing.numberOfRooms} rooms
                | {listing.numberOfBeds} beds | {listing.numberOfBaths} baths
              </Typography>
              <Typography color='textSecondary'>
                {listing.location.city}, {listing.location.state}
              </Typography>
            </Container>
          </Row>

          <Row justify='center'>
            <Col>
              <Container className={classes.listingView}>
                <Carousel>
                  {listing.imgUrls &&
                    listing.imgUrls.map((img) => (
                      <div>
                        <img src={img} className={classes.listingImg}></img>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                </Carousel>
              </Container>
            </Col>

            <Col>
              <Container className={classes.bookingView}>
                <Typography align='center' variant='h5'>
                  Reserve Here
                </Typography>
                <Divider />
                <ReserveForm listing={listing} />
              </Container>
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row justify='center'>
            <Container className={classes.listingDetails} maxWidth='md'>
              <Typography variant='h5'>Entire Place Hosted By Maria</Typography>
              <Divider />
              <Typography variant='h3'>Amenities</Typography>
              <Row gutter={16}>
                {listing.amenities &&
                  listing.amenities.map((amen) => (
                    <Col>
                      <Typography variant='h6'>{amen}</Typography>
                    </Col>
                  ))}
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </Row>

          <Row justify='center'>
            <Container maxWidth='md' className={classes.reviewView}>
              <Typography variant='h4'>Reviews</Typography>
              <Reviews listingId={listingId} />
              <ReviewForm listingId={listingId} />
            </Container>
          </Row>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Detail;
```

Comment: listing?.location?.city this might work or you can add check too to prevent error. Can you please share your sample response??

Comment: @VaibhavGidde This worked! What exactly happens with that??